# How to Change What Menu Pops up When You Save A File

Tags: 20.04, gtk

whenever I save a file, all gtk applications use one thing to save it. The same application is used for opening a file too. Is there any way to change what is used? Preferably to something that is vim like, maybe vifm if it can do that. Thanks for help!
-Diego

Comment: Welcome! It's not clear what you are asking. "all gtk applications use one thing to save it". Could you explain in more detail what do you mean by that?

Comment: I believe you are referring to the **file picker** or **file selection dialog**, but it's not clear what you want when you say you want it to be vim-like.  You need to tell us what that entails.  GTK applications are going to use the GTK file picker.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! By vim like, I mean that it can be used with the hjkl keys or similar. I was wondering if I could use something else than the GTK file picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without deep hacking into the system.

Applications are responsible to provide their interface to open or save files. However, for these common requirements, toolkits do provide dialog that applications can call for this function. This eliminates the need for the programmer to implement such dialog himself, and provides a more consistent experience to the user.

Many applications take advantage of this and will call the default dialogs of the toolkit in use by the desktop. Thus, on Ubuntu 20.04, that uses Gnome Shell, many applications will use GTK3 dialogs, even by applications that are developed on top of a different toolkit such as QT or others. Some older GTK2 applications will use GTK2 dialogs. If you move to a Plasma desktop, which is build with the QT toolkit, QT file dialogs commonly will be used.

So in the end, it might be possible to redirect these calls to the standard dialogs to your custom dialogs, but that would require replacing standard libraries by your custom libraries, which would need to expose the same interface to the calling applications.

Comment: Thanks! From what I learned from your answer I was able to research a bit more and found this: https://superuser.com/questions/944119/replace-gtk-file-dialog-with-alternative Hopefully I will be able to find some way to change the dialog to something keyboard driven rather than the kde file selector.

Comment: Glad this helped a bit!